# WEBRIck not booting up..getting error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Here is the new error message I am getting when doing rails s....

> Exiting
>   C:/Sites/ThinkBlog/crumblr/config/initializers/devise.rb:235:in `block
>   in &lt;top (required)&gt;': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass
>   (NoMethodError) from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise.rb:292:in
>   `setup' from
>   C:/Sites/ThinkBlog/crumblr/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in`<top
>   (required)>' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'

By the way line 235 in device.rb is ,

```
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['facebook_api_key'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['facebook_api_secret']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages tells you exactly what is wrong with your code: `undefined method[]' for nil` or in other words: You try to call the `[]` method on an object the is `nil`.

Since you only call `[]` on `FACEBOOK_CONFIG` the only reason for this errors is: `FACEBOOK_CONFIG` is not initialized and therefore `nil`.

Comment: Thank you spickermann, I will see how i can initialize FACEBOOK_CONFIG and I will be back..

Comment: This is how my FACEBOOK_CONFIG looks like :   FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[::Rails.env]

Comment: Not sure why it is not initialized..I did change # in the above code where it was $ before.

Comment: In what file do you set that constant? The `$` variables are global variables and accessable from evrywhere in the app. Upcase constants might be scoped with the namespace.

Comment: FACEBOOK_CONFIG is in initializers sub-folder under config folder. That constant is called from devise.rb file which is also in initializers sub-folder. Is that what you wanted to know or mean? Let me know i will provide more detail.

Comment: What are the names of the files? IMO Rails loads the files in the initializers folder in alphabetically order. What means a `devise.rb` file whould be loaded and processed, before a `facebook.rb` file would be able to set that constant. (Beside that please forget me comment about the `$`, I misunderstood one of your comments...)

Comment: oh I know what you mean. The name of the file starts with a, so I have made sure that it gets initialized before devise.rb. Something else seems to be not working.